# brand banner image changed to bad quality

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I add a brand image logo, like this...image shows bad quality.
How can I make brand logo image shows it's original quality.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?=$g4['path']?>/">
    <img src="<?=$g4[path]?>/images/logo_opencode.gif" align=absmiddle alt="brand logo">
</a>
```

bootstrap 3 customize values..
@navbar-default-bg #3aba1a
@navbar-default-link-color #fff

[image: bad qualty banner]
<sub>(source: [opencode.co.kr](http://opencode.co.kr/data/file/css/1401/1389493430_vWIYN9gi_logo_2.png))</sub>

Comment: Use PNG with transparent background, get help from a professional to create logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving it in PNG 8-bit with transparency or PNG 24-bit with transparency.

OR open in the image editor that you created your logo, change the background of the image to the same of the navbar and save it.

Comment: it is a gif logo with transparent background.

Comment: If your problem with the logo is that white noise around the logo, it is because it was made transparent and it is a common problem with "low-quality transparency". That can happens to .gif files and .png 8-bit with low transparency.

Comment: I had the same problem about 2 months ago. There is only 3 possible ways to solve it : `1) Save as 8-bit PNG with transparency and highest pallete/quality`; `2) Save as 24-bit PNG`; `3) Save without transparency`

Comment: You're welcome! At my website i had the same problem and choose to use it as 8-bit png without transparency to avoid any conflict with old browsers :P

Comment: Be aware that IE6 render the PNG transparency as a grayish color

Comment: 1st way - save as 8-bit png with transparency works well. image changes to clear. thanks....